# A Service error occurred while uploading video to youtube channel

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube api 3 to upload video to my youtube channel . The following error occurs on some browser.

> A service error occured: { "error": [{ "domain": "global", "reason" :
>   "authError", "message": "Invalide Credentials", "locationType":
>   "header","location": "Authorization"}],"code":401,"message": "Invalid
>   Credentials"}

I used the code from [youtube api quick start](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/php) and changed it a little bit to bypass authorization by using access token and refresh token. 
This error is occurring on some browsers where gmail is already signed in.

link to my uploader is
http://nearhero.com/upoadVideos/uploadonyoutube/resumable_upload.php?title=testit_&des=description&v_name=test.mp4

Answer (score 0):

> "code":401,"message": "Invalid Credentials"

Normally means that the client id and secret you are using are not valid with Google.  Either you have copied them incorrectly or they were deleted on Google developer console.

I recommend downloading the credentials file from google again and trying that.   Remember that any refresh token you have stored may not work with these new credentials you will need to authenticate again.

Comment: the problem is that majority of the times the code works and uploads the video to my channel but sometimes this error occurs

Comment: Then i think you should go though your code it sounds like you have a section where sometimes you load the wrong credentials file.

Comment: ok thanks I will go through the code once again and let you know